# Sort array of objects, add sorted index to each object, then return to original sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
  const array = [
    { name: 'b' },
    { name: 'a' },
    { name: 'c' },
  ]
```

The goal here is to keep the same array but to add a new property on each object based on its position if the array was sorted:

```
  const array = [
    { name: 'b', sortIndex: 1 },
    { name: 'a', sortIndex: 0 },
    { name: 'c', sortIndex: 2 },
  ]
```

I came up with a plan to just sort the array based on the name. Then loop through it and add the index to get this:

```
 const array = [
   { name: 'a', sortIndex: 0 },
   { name: 'b', sortIndex: 1 },
   { name: 'c', sortIndex: 2 },
 ]
```

Then I would loop through the original array and do a findIndex against the sorted array to get the index but that seems like terrible code with so many loops and stuff. Any ideas on how to make this better?

```
export function setSortIndexes(series) {
  const clone = cloneDeep(series);
  const sorted = orderBy(clone, [
    (x) => (x.name ? x.name.toLowerCase() : null),
  ]);

  sorted.forEach((x, i) => {
    x.sortIndex = i;
  });

  series.forEach(x => {
    const index = sorted.findIndex((s) => s.name === x.name);

    if (index !== -1) {
      x.sortIndex = sorted[index].sortIndex;
    }
  });

  return series;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look that bad to me: https://jsfiddle.net/z5cqt9La/

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @ChrisG thats alot better than what i have and it works well. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do that:
no need to duplicate objects (or some of its elements) in a new array. an array of pointers to these objects is sufficient

```js
const array = 
  [ { name: 'b'} 
  , { name: 'a'} 
  , { name: 'c'} 
  ] 
array                  // create a new array  
  .map(o=>({o}))      // of pointers ( o ) to refer each array objects
  .sort((a,b)=>a.o.name.localeCompare(b.o.name)) // sort 
  .forEach((_,i,a)=>a[i].o.sortIndex = i )      // add the sortIndex attr 


console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary array to sort, including the original index.
Sort by the name field
Add index to the original object.

```
array
  .map((e, i) => ({ name: e.name, originalIndex: i }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  .forEach((e, i) => array[e.originalIndex].sortIndex = i)
```